# Disable Advanced Filter in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I was wondering if anyone could help me to disable the Advanced Filter option in Excel 2013.

I have used the following to disable all other data ribbon options:

```
.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

But advanced filter is still able to be selected. With this they can unfilter the data.

The following code used to work in older versions of Excel but I cannot seem to get it to work for Excel 2013:

```
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls _
    ("&Data").Controls("&Filter").Controls("&Advanced Filter...").Enabled = False
```

If anyone could help me out with this or point me in the right direction then it would be appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from preventing someone from changing the filters? If you have data you don't want people to view, then only grant access to an edited document. Anyone with access to your filtered spreadsheet could still read the underlying file to view the hidden data.

Comment: Hi Phylogenesis. I have written the code to detect the users employee ID based on the computer username `Int(Environ("Username"))` and it filters the data to only show their data. I have protected the sheet so they cannot access anything else but the Advanced filter option is causing the problem. I understand that if they really want to get in to the code to disable this then they can but this is just to stop most users from getting access to this.

Comment: The problem is that you can read the file outside of Excel (or use VBA) to read the hidden data. If you're doing this for security reasons, it's pretty much a waste of time.

Comment: It is partially for security but I understand that if they really want access to the data they can get it. However they would need to go out of their way to access this if I can disable Advanced filter. Even so I would like to understand if this is possible in Excel 2013 or if they have stopped us from disabling this. Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: there are numerous possibilities to bypass Excel security (if you can even call that) once you allow someone to open an Excel file. Just remember that the protection is only as good as the software enforcing it. Excel files cannot only be opened with MS Excel! And there are numerous programs out there which simply don't enforce  *any* kind of protection once the file is open. Yet, a bit easier: just create a new empty Excel file and put in cell `A1` the formula `=[ProtectedExcelFile.xlsm]Sheet1!A1` and copy the formula down and across. And there you have an unprotected copy.

Comment: Seriously I think we understand that someone CAN get to the data if they want to. I myself would like an answer to the question however. If one of my employees loads up the program and accesses the data then that's enough for me to prove their bad actions and fire them. I need a "nuisance lock"  to keep my good employees from accidentally seeing what they didn't mean to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution Suggested***
The approach will be hiding the button from the user interface: the advantage on this solution is that the code is not in VBA (entirely) so, *is not that easy* for the user to modify it (or know what is going on backstage).

***Answer Explanation/Next steps***
It's really a deep answer with many steps involved in it so, I'll just post guidance and some useful links, that way you may research about it first. 

1. Download [Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/06/7293.aspx): this helps to modify the user interface for the document.

2. Look for tutorials; start to code there with something basic like adding a tab and a button, [(this is a good one)](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm)

3. Back to Excel, look for life cycle and custom events, [this is a good place to start](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)

4. You'll need to catch the event when the Ribbon is loaded; in that time, you'd need to  disable the button, these links ([1](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm),[2](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win013.htm)) are useful to show the steps and some example workbooks for it.

5. Locate the ID for the button and disable it (Hint: The idMSO = AdvancedFilterDialog, if you 've followed the previous steps, it will make sense here-).

***Further information/Answer Disclaimer***

Excel is not a software that can handle security deeply; if you are trying to restrict the user somehow in the original file, you should try other approaches -IG: a copy of a workbook for reference only, while the master one is saved in a sharepoint only modifiable by people authorized for it-.

 While FAQ in S.O is strict about referencing to other sites without using a proper reference for it, this is a deep step solution that would take pages to explain even a random example; appealing to the guiding topic, this answer should be ok.